# Is dandruff bad?

Tags: hair, hairloss, dandruff

I have a lot of Dandruff and I am just starting to lose hair. Is there any co-relation. I heard Dandruff is neither good nor bad, it is quantitative. Meaning that everybody has it, but on different levels. For some it  is not visible, but they do have it and others have a lot of it.

Is this true? More over is dandruff bad for my hair. Does it Cause hairfall?

Comment: You're going to need to define "bad."

Comment: @CareyGregory bad for hairfall?

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Dandruff is flaking of your scalp. It can happen for lots of reasons and a common misconception is that it's due to improper washing or hygiene issues. That's not necessarily true, it can depend on a number of factors including how often you wash your hair or if you use a lot of hair product. I've had it before as a 12 year old and my dermatologist informed me it was due to washing my hair too much and wearing a hat all the time.

Comment: @MasterYoda this should be an answer +1 thanks